# How to move panel smoothly by 3 in c# windows application without flickering

Tags: c#, windows, picturebox, smoothing

I am developing the windows application for real time application. I am showing the image line by line within while loop using `picturebox` as follows,

```
Lclone = (System.Drawing.Image)imagedata.Clone();
pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => pictureBox1.Image = Lclone));
```

Here `imagedata` is a bitmap and showing it in `picturebox` and `picturebox` is in panel, according to that I want to move panel by 3 for image rolling effect & I had done it already but it gives me flickering effect and I want this movement smoothly.

How can I do this?

Comment: Truely smooth movement will not be possible with winforms but flicker can be avoided. Give us a few numbers: how often do you call it and how large is the image? Also: How does this code move anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is accessible from outside, but you can try to set `DoubleBuffered = true` to the picturebox. If it is not accessible from you would have to create your own child class that inherits picturebox in which you set the `DoubleBuffered` property.

Comment: PictureBoxes are doublebuffered by default. Panels can't be double-buffered without subclassing them